# Tensor product of modules and injective map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

$(R,m)$ is a local ring, $M,N$ are $R$-modules.
$M$ is finitely generated and free.
$N$ is generated by only $y$.

Then is $f:M\otimes N\to M, f(x\otimes y)=x$ injective?

Comment: Take $R$ to be a field so that $M$ and $N$ are vector spaces. What is $f \colon M \otimes N \to N$ like in that case?

Comment: Before asking for injectivity, you should ascertain you have a map to begin with. What you have is not well-defined, as far as I can see.

Comment: As the others have said, there is no such map. Remember that to define a map out of a tensor product you can write down a map on pure tensors but *then* you have to check that it's bilinear, which you have not; this map is not linear in $y$ so it does not define a map out of the tensor product at all. A true map out of the tensor product, for example, always satisfies $f(x \otimes 0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such map. Consider the case when $M=R$ and $N=R/I$, where $I$ is an ideal. Then $R\otimes_R R/I\cong R/I$ and there's no reason for the existence of *any* nontrivial homomorphism $R/I\to R$.